# My mail server using IRedMail (postfix, dovecot, etc.) is only sending and receiving local emails?

Tags: email, nginx, dns, debian, postfix-mta

I recently set up a mail server using IRedMail on a home server running Debian 8, using OpenLDAP, nginx in the installer. We got everything set up and configured to where we can access our mail server with roundcube (which I can access through mail.sterango.com) and Thunderbird and login to accounts just fine. We can send emails to and from accounts that are on the domain (seb@sterango.com can send and receive from postmaster@smail.sterango.com), but I am not able to send or recieve email with either of these accounts from outside sources such as my gmail account.
Here is my main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.sterango.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
myorigin = mail.sterango.com
mydestination = 
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
inet_protocols = ipv4
virtual_alias_domains = 
mydomain = mail.sterango.com
allow_percent_hack = no
swap_bangpath = no
mynetworks_style = host
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile
smtp_tls_loglevel = 0
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unlisted_sender, permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated
delay_warning_time = 0h
maximal_queue_lifetime = 4h
bounce_queue_lifetime = 4h
proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions
smtp_data_init_timeout = 240s
smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 600s
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
queue_run_delay = 300s
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
enable_original_recipient = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
allow_min_user = no
message_size_limit = 15728640
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
relay_domains = $mydestination, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unlisted_recipient, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
default_transport = smtp
```

Also here are my DNS records: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKDkk.png
Should the A one point to a local IP like that? 
I will also gladly post any logs or files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Reverse DNS - the outside world will expect that the source address of email you're sending has a correct reverse lookup. 192.168.x.x is a private IP address and is therefore not an appropriate reverse lookup. Specifically, the name in `myorigin` needs to have a correct reverse. If this is not correct, your spam score shoots WAY up on services like gmail.
2. `mynetworks` indicates that you're only processing mail for localhost, are you sure you're listening on a non-localhost interface?
3. your logs are one of the best methods of troubleshooting postfix, but they can also be somewhat misleading when troubleshooting remote delivery. Many services will accept mail from suspected spam sources with no indication that they're going to toss out or tag the incoming mail as spam because that would make it easier to bypass their spam filters.

Comment: both my mailserver and webserver public ips are the same and running off seperate computers??

Comment: if you have a mail and web server running on different computers, but using the same address, then you most likely have a NAT somewhere in between them and the internet

Comment: do you have a person that is in charge of your network connections? that's who you need to speak to regarding NAT.